# Adding code to bottom navigation android studio

Tags: javascript, android, android-bottomnavigationview

I have made a simple app using Android Studio with bottom navigation. It all works well until I add code to the Fragments. Where is the place I need to add code in this example?

This part is written in the activity of a fragment. I have placed the variables in Public Class, and wanted to write the code in "public void onCreate", but the app crashed if I try to write anything there (even the most basic like declaring a variable).

My question is: in which part I should write the code? I am trying to put a simple Timer on this Fragment.

Hope my question is clear this time, first time posting here.

```
    package com.example.testfitnessapp;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.SystemClock;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;

public class TrainingFragment extends Fragment {


    Button start, pause, reset;
    View textView;
    Handler handler;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_training, container, false);
    }

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // do your variables initialisations here except Views!!!

    }

    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        // initialise your views

    }

}
```

Comment: You have to add more details. What is the problem? Please add error log. And don't use an image for the code, use \`code\` please.

Comment: Please do not post code inside screen shots. Code is text and should be pasted as text (formatted as code) into your post.

Comment: Where do you write your code? Which Section? does your app support Data Binding? Does your Bottom Navigation placed in your fragment? or what? we need more details :-D

Comment: For anyone who is interested, I have fixed it myself. The problem was that the variables need to be declared in main class (so after "public class TrainingFragment extends Fragment") and then the code needs to be written after "public void onViewCreated". First the view is inflated with "public View onCreateView" and after view is created you can execute code. The " public void onCreate" method is not needed and I have removed it.

Comment: @Jan... Post an answer to your question then